# Custom ERB tag replacement

Tags: ruby, erb

How can I get ERB to replace tags in a format other than

```
<%= %>
```

for example:

```
{{   }}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
ERB.new(your_template.gsub("{{", "<%=").gsub("}}", "%>")).result
```

I don't think there is an option to tell ERB to use different tags.

But you can use [`liquid`](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) library which uses this curly braces syntax.

Comment: i used eRubis in the end, this allows customisation

Answer (score 1):

I believe ERb also supports inline interpolated strings (`#{}`) in place of percent brackets, so perhaps that might better suit your needs?

Comment: It can be surprisingly easy to forget that you can do this.